# Can I customize UIPickerView like this?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have to making UIPickerView.
My designer request like this.
[image]

But iOS default UIPickerView is not working like that.
So I think I have to customize UIPickerView.
But is it possible?
I don't know if it's possible to implement it because it's not just different colors.

Comment: It isn't clear specifically what you are asking, but there is limited visual customisation of `UIPickerView` available; you might have to create your own component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is limited visual customisation of UIPickerView available; you might have to create your own component or you can use library [Check This](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#pickerview).